# Prior art request US20130195410

Tags: prior-art-request, us20130195410

In reference to the patent: [US20130195410](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130195410)

This was described in a 1989 Paper in Physical Review Letters Volume 62 Number 1 published 2 January 1989 in a paper titled "[Transverse Localization of Light](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.62.47)"

Comment: Unfortunately, the referenced paper is behind a paywall and isn't available to be read. When evaluating whether the paper teaches what is in the patent, focus specifically on the claims.